# xUnit: stop test execution from code

Tags: c#, unit-testing, xunit

Can I finish the unit test from code? Is it possible to do something like this?

```
[Fact]
public void Test()
{
   code;
   code;
   code;
   StopUnitTest(success: true);
   code;
   code;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really sure why one would do that and I know it's maybe a bit too late to reply. However, the usage of `goto` keyword could potentially solve this.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/goto

Comment: I don't remember why I needed it, but yes, that solves it.